# How increment id tag with map function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array in react like

```
[
{
  no:"s1",
  name:"abcd"
},
{
  no:"s1",
  name:"abcd"
}
]
```

I want to use map function to render in UI but. I want id to be increment with map integrations

eg

```
<ul>
   <li id="1">
     {no}
     {name}
   </li>
  <li id="2">
     {no}
     {name}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is not how you create an array.. also, array in js, not in react, its just a library

Comment: Use `index + 1` in id? index is the second parameter in the `map` callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use array `index` for that

```
const data = [
{
  no:"s1",
  name:"abcd"
},
{
  no:"s1",
  name:"abcd"
}
]
...
return <ul>
  {data.map((item, i) => <li key={i} id={i+1}>{item.no} {item.name}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: The data is invalid?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes I've copied the data from the question and I didn't notice it